# Is there a way to avoid manually configuring git flow?

Tags: git, git-flow

Scenario: the use of `git flow` is encouraged with a particular repository.  Now anyone who checks out the repository must run `git flow init` and hope that the default conventions/settings are correct for this repository.

Is there a way to have the repository directly tell `git flow init` what settings it should use, without prompting the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `.gitconfig` (or whatever you want to call it) in your project repository and commit it.

You will need to run a `git config` command (see below) to tell git to use this file, and it will then use the defaults specified in it.

The `-d` option in `git flow init` tells it to use the defaults, and not prompt the user.

It does add an extra command that needs to be run (the local config setting) but I don't see a way you can do this without asking the user to run some custom commands.

#### Sample `.gitconfig`

```
[gitflow "branch"]
        master = m
        develop = d
[gitflow "prefix"]
        feature = f/
        bugfix = b/
        release = r/
```

#### Setting up

```
git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig
git flow init -d
```

#### Result

```
$ git branch
* d
  m

$ git flow feature start foo
Switched to a new branch 'f/foo'

Summary of actions:
- A new branch 'f/foo' was created, based on 'd'
- You are now on branch 'f/foo'
```